# How can I see my nvidia quadro 6000 in 2.80, 2.81 CUDA?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I bought my computer two years ago.
In 2.79 or earlier I can see my quadro 6000 listed in the CUDA settings but now, starting with 2.80 I cannot see it.
Is there any way to fix this problem? I am using Windows 10 and I already updated my driver, but still, no change.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The requirements for GPU rendering are higher than the [minimum requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) for running Blender.

> **Supported Graphics Cards**
>
> These requirements are for basic Blender operation, rendering using the GPU requires slightly different [requirements](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#supported-hardware).

The [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#nvidia-cuda) states that CUDA compute capability 3.0 or higher is required for GPU rendering. Graphics cards that do not meet that requirement will not be listed in the preferences.

> **NVIDIA CUDA**
>
> NVIDIA CUDA is supported for GPU rendering with NVIDIA graphics cards. Blender supports graphics cards with compute capability 3.0 and higher. To make sure your GPU is supported, see the [list of NVIDIA graphics cards](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus) with the compute capabilities and supported graphics cards.
>
> NVIDIA CUDA GPU rendering is supported on Windows, macOS, and Linux.

Since the [Quadro 6000 has compute capability 2.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA) it's not supported for GPU rendering.